# How to extract the first element that match a condition from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to extract the first element of an array that match a condition.

Imagine that I have this array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

How can I extract the first element that is greater than 4 obtaining the array `[1,2,3,4,6,7]` and the extracted element `5`?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to modify the original array `a` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Approach 1:

```
ar - [ele = ar.select{|a| a > 4 }.first]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]

ele
#=> 5

ar
#=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Approach 2:

```
ar_selected = ar.select{|a| a > 4 }
ar_pruned, first_matched_ele = ar - [ar_selected.first], ar_selected.first
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], 5]

first_matched_ele
#=> 5

ar_pruned
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]

ar
#=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: Instead of `ar.select{|a| a > 4 }.first` you can use `ar.detect{|a| a > 4 }`

Answer (score 5):

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
found = ar.delete_at(ar.index{|el| el>4})
p found # => 5
p ar    # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Good! But deleting from `self`.. That is the point I am worrying. :(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `Array` contains only unique elements I am not sure why no one mentioned the `find` method which does exactly what you want.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = a.delete(a.find{|n| n > 4}) 
#=> 5
a
#=> [1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

Or non destructively (now the original array still exists in `original_a`, `b` is the first element that meets the criteria and `a` is now the modified `Array`)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
original_a,b = a.dup, a.delete(a.find{|e| e > 4})
original_a
#=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b
#=> 5
a 
#=>[1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ind = a.index { |i| i > 4 }
rest_indices = [*0...a.size] - [ind]
first,ary = a[ind],a.values_at(*rest_indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using [`Enumerable#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
found = false
elem, arr = a.partition { |x| (!found) && (found||= x>4) }
# => [[5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]] 
elem
#=> [5]
arr
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and then delete the found element:

```
index = a.index { |i| i > 4 }
first_element = a[index]
a.delete_at index
```

Comment: This will delete all 5's, not just the first one.

Comment: Indeed, it will. I changed my code to delete with the index instead.